# How to get NavigationController from Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios5

I have a storyboard with a View Controller has my initial view.  I am trying to segue to a NavigationController from a button click.

I can make the segue work when the button is clicked, but how do I get a reference to my NavigationController so I can populate my TableView?

Also, how do I make the table view go back to the initial view?

My Storyboard looks like this:

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First, in general we don't segue *to* nav controller, we segue *with* them, to another view controller. In theory, your segue will only work (unless you have done a lot of unnecessary coding) if you have properly setup the storyboard to make the Navigation controller the "initial" view controller, and your first View Controller as it's "root view controller" (most easily accomplished by the menu's "Embed in... > Navigation Controller" command).

Then in your code, you *always* have a simple access point for your nav controller: Any view controller which is currently *in the stack* of controllers managed by a nav controller can simply use it's `navigationController` property to access it. You can then use [it's interface](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to [popViewControllerAnimated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW3) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

In your View Controller, implement

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

and get your `NavigationController` via `segue.destinationViewController`.

But if you want to go back, you probably want the ViewController with the button to be connected to the NavigationController, not the other way around.

NC => VC with button -> TableVC

where => is a relationship segue and -> is a push segue.

Comment: I have updated the post with a screenshot of my storyboard. Maybe that will be helpful.  Basically when I button is pushed I want to display a list of items that the user can choose and get details on on the in a subsequent view... does that makes sense?

Comment: In your case, you can get back by sending the NavigationController a -dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: message.

Comment: Doesn't a navigation controller have a back button by default?

Comment: The Back-Button is for the above mentioned case, when the next level connected via a push segue has been displayed. See also the other answer.